# d3 + google map -- remove data points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711 as a basis to draw a google map which has points from a datatables table. When I filter the datatables table I want the points on the map to be filtered as such.

When I use `exit().remove()` for some reason all the points are removed.

To simulate my code I forked Mike's example and added the exit().remove() call. See https://bl.ocks.org/louking/a62333735faca758cb70d431b790f463

As you can see, the block

```
  // trying to remove points which do not show up on reload
    .exit().remove()
  // end trying to remove points which do not show up on reload
```

causes the points to all disappear.

How can I resolve this? And please explain what is going on here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can all enter or exit methods only on selections. 
You can go through this short tutorial on d3 update pattern [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpeOzq8eDYk&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p&index=8).

```
// trying to remove points which do not show up on reload
marker.exit().remove()
// end trying to remove points which do not show up on reload 
marker.enter().append("svg")
      .each(transform)
      .attr("class", "marker");
```

Comment: The link you posted was on transitions. I was using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 as guidance. Seems like the mistake I made was assuming that marker was returned after var marker = layer.selectAll("svg").data(d3.entries(data)).each(transform). Working version is in https://codepen.io/louking/pen/zPreZR